# Can I use HOC to wrap component with graphql and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, higher-order-components

I have plenty of template components, they resemble each other in way they are used.
Before being rendered to page, template components get wrapped in graphql and connected to redux.
I want to create a HOC to wrap my templates, so that I do not create a new container each time to connect template to data.
Like so:

Here is my page component, where I try to wrap the **AppointmentsListTemplate** template with **gqlList** HOC:

```
import React from 'react'
import { AdminTemplate, AppointmentsListTemplate } from 'components'
import { gqlList } from 'containers'
import {qyListAppointments} from 'services/gqlQueries/Appointments'

const AppointmentsListTemplateWrapped = gqlList(AppointmentsListTemplate, qyListAppointments)

const AdminAppointmentsPage = (props) => {
    return (
        <AdminTemplate>
            <AppointmentsListTemplateWrapped />
        </AdminTemplate>
    )
}

export default AdminAppointmentsPage
```

And here is my gqlList HOC:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { saveQueryVars } from 'store/helper/actions'

const gqlList = (WrappedComponent, gqlQuery) => {

  const GQL = graphql(gqlQuery)(WrappedComponent)
  return connect(null, {
    saveQueryVars,
  })(GQL)
}
export default gqlList
```

But graphql connector part throws me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined
>       at getDisplayName (react-apollo.browser.umd.js:250)
>       at wrapWithApolloComponent (react-apollo.browser.umd.js:266)
>       at new eval (gqlList.js:22)
>       at eval (createClassProxy.js:95)
>       at instantiate (createClassProxy.js:103)
>       at Unknown (eval at proxyClass (createClassProxy.js:NaN), :4:17)
>       at eval (ReactCompositeComponent.js:303)
>       at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:73)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `AppointmentsListTemplate` seems undefined when you pass it to the hoc. Can you make sure something comes out `{ AppointmentsListTemplate } from 'components'` ?

Comment: Yes, it does come.
When I try to render this way, it works:
`const AdminAppointmentsPage = (props) => {
    return (
        <AdminTemplate>
            <AppointmentsListTemplate />
        </AdminTemplate>
    )
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code, as far as I can tell. I would also rule out redux as the source of the error. But here's what I suggest:

Check your GraphQL query (gqlQuery) so that it gets what it needs and it can return what you need. I suspect it requires some parameters but doesn't get the right type of a parameter - resulting in a Type error.
Here's an example (without redux) of how to pass parameters:

```
const Data = graphql(fetchData, { options: {variables: {id: this.getId()} }})(Thing);
```

Here, fetchData requires the id of a Thing and returns data about that thing. Then you can render `<Data/>.`

You might want to improve your question by adding the query and variables (saveQueryVars) to it. Also, mention the version of react-apollo because that's the module throwing the error. As a side note, the error message coming from the Apollo client is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain them together:

```
import { changeFoo } from './myReduxActions';

const QUERY = gql`{ FindSomething { Id, Value }}`;

const myComponent = connect(
   store => ({
      foo: store.fooReducer.foo
   }),
   dispatch => ({
      changeFoo: (val) => dispatch(changeFoo(val))
   })
)(graphql(QUERY)(
   {props.data.loading && return <div>Loading...</div>}

   let myNewFoo = 'abc';
   return props.data.FindSomething ?
       <div>{`Id is ${props.data.FindSomething.Id}, redux store value foo is ${props.foo}`}
       <div onClick={() => props.ChangeFoo(myNewFoo)}></div></div> :
       props.data.error ? <div>Error {props.data.error}</div> : null;
));
```

So you could do `connect(graphql(pureComponent)))` or written as `connect => graphql => component`. You can change the order of graphql and connect.